# How to lock out user after X amount of inactivity?

Tags: java, android, android-activity, android-context

I need to show an `Activity` each time a user is inactive for X amount of time. I am trying to achieve that with a custom `CountDownTimer`, which starts `onUserInteraction` in my `BaseActivity`:

```
@Override
public void onUserInteraction() {
    super.onUserInteraction();
    inactivityTimer.cancel();
    inactivityTimer.start();
}
```

In my custom `CountDownTimer`, I start the desired `Activity` `onFinish`:

```
@Override
public void onFinish() {
    BaseActivity baseActivity = new BaseActivity();
    Log.i("TIMER ENDED: ", "NOW STARTING LOCKACTIVITY");
    baseActivity.showLock();
}
```

And this is my `showLock()` method in `BaseActivity`

```
public void showLock() {
    Intent intent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), LockActivity.class);
    startActivity(intent);
}
```

What I'm getting is a NPE every time the timer ends. (`java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'java.lang.String android.content.Context.getPackageName()' on a null object reference`) even though I tried using `getApplication().getBaseContext()`, `this`, `this.getBaseContext()`, `this.getApplicationContext()`,  `getApplicationContext()`and
`getBaseContext()` instead of `getApplicationContext()`

However, if I set the `Context` in the method call like this:

```
@Override
public void onFinish() {
    BaseActivity baseActivity = new BaseActivity();
    Context context = MyApplication.getInstance().getApplicationContext();
    Log.i("TIMER ENDED: ", "NOW STARTING LOCKACTIVITY");
    baseActivity.showLock(context);
}
```

And this in `showLock()`:

```
public void showLock(Context context) {
    Intent intent = new Intent(context, LockActivity.class);
    startActivity(intent);
}
```

This time I get another NPE (`java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'android.app.ActivityThread$ApplicationThread android.app.ActivityThread.getApplicationThread()' on a null object reference`).

So my question is, how do I get a proper `Context` every time my `showLock()` is called from the current `Activity`, which will be calling that method?

**Important note:** each and every `Activity` in my project inherits `BaseActivity`, which on its own inherits `AppCompatActivity`.

#### **EDIT**

I gave Marcin's suggestion a try and after dealing with a couple of errors I ended up using his approach. If someone else is curious and wants to know how to open an activity after X amount of inactivity this worked for me:

Since all my Activities inherit one main `BaseActivity` I put there a custom  `Handler`, which holds a `WeakReference` to said `BaseActivity`. I also overrode `handleMessage`, where I call my desired method:

```
private static class InactivityHandler extends Handler {
    private WeakReference<BaseActivity> baseActivityWeakReference;

    private InactivityHandler(BaseActivity baseActivity) {
        baseActivityWeakReference = new WeakReference<>(baseActivity);
    }

    @Override
    public void handleMessage(Message msg) {
        BaseActivity baseActivity = baseActivityWeakReference.get();
        if (baseActivity != null) {
            baseActivity.showLock();
        }
    }
}
```

and in `onUserInteraction` send a `Message` to the queue after some time:

```
@Override
public void onUserInteraction() {
    super.onUserInteraction();
    inactivityHandler.removeMessages(MESSAGE_WHAT, MESSAGE_TOKEN);
    inactivityHandler.sendMessageDelayed(inactivityHandler.obtainMessage(MESSAGE_WHAT, MESSAGE_TOKEN), DELAY_TIME);
}
```

And for the curious, here is my `showLock` method:

```
public void showLock() {
    Intent intent = new Intent(this, LockActivity.class);
    startActivity(intent);
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From you description I assume that after the user is inactive for some time your app needs to present a lock screen where the user needs to reenter their credentials.

Unless the whole scenario has any counting involved (for example you display an actual count down), a `CountDownTimer` may not be the best to perform this task.

Instead you could use a `Handler`. In Android, the Main Thread has it's associated message queue. Handlers are able to post messages to this queue to receive them later, at the given time.

Your example implementation could look like that:

```
private static class LockScreenHandler extends Handler {
  private WeakReference<BaseActivity> activityRef;

  public LockScreenHandler(BaseActivity activity) {
    activityRef = new WeakReference<>(activity);
  }

  @Override public handleMessage(Message msg) {
    BaseActivity activity = activityRef.get();

    if (activity != null) {
      activity.showLock();
    } // Otherwise the activity got destroyed in the meantime
  }
}
```

You may send either Runnables or Messages with the Handler. In our case a Message is perfectly fine. Therefore in your Base Activity you may have some Message-related fields:

```
private static final int MESSAGE_WHAT = 1;
private static final Object MESSAGE_TOKEN = new Object();
```

And then you use your handler in onUserInteraction:

```
@Override public void onUserInteraction() {
  super.onUserInteraction();
  handler.removeMessages(MESSAGE_WHAT, MESSAGE_TOKEN);
  handler.postDelayed(handler.obtainMessage(MESSAGE_WHAT, MESSAGE_TOKEN), INACTIVITY_DELAY);
}
```

If you decide to follow your CountDownTimer solution you may follow the same technique, by creating a static inner class and giving your activity in the constructor.

Whichever way you go, it is important to note, that your BaseActivity can be destroyed by the system and improper usage of Handler (and CountDownTimer which internally relies on Handler) can prevent the reference to this activity from being destroyed and therefore lead to a memory leak. Therefore:

- If you use a Handler or a CountDownTimer as an inner class, make sure it is `static`. Non-static inner classes hold a reference to their enclosing classes. Messages hold references to their target Handlers, so as long as the message is in the queue it's handler cannot get destroyed.
- Use a WeakReference to hold your activity for the same reason as outlined above. WeakReferences are cleared if nothing else holds a reference to the given object.

Comment: I took my time to redo the whole thing the way you suggested, and after dealing with a couple of errors here and there it worked. Thank you for your time and effort, it's much appreciated!

Answer (score 1):

An Activity **is** a Context itself. So just use `this` within an Activity.

```
public void showLock() {
    Intent intent = new Intent(this, LockActivity.class);
    startActivity(intent);
}
```

Comment: I tried using `this`. Edited the question with a bit more information.

Comment: `this` in BaseActivity will refer to the actual activity calling the method. It does not refer to BaseActivity

Comment: Only running Activities have Context. BaseActivity is not running, just like class Activity. Does it work if you use `this`? The behavior of an Activity is not influenced by where it was started from.

Comment: I thought so too, but it throws the same NPE when I use `this`.

Comment: It is the newly started activity that caused the exception, I think. If an app crashes within an activity's onCreate Android just say "unable to start activity" and act as if the previous activity caused it.

Answer (score 0):

If this is not an option because you are overriding a function you should use MainActivity.this (when the MainActivity is the name of your activity)

```
MainActivity.this.startActivity(MainActivity.this, ...);
```